# after executing the keystore command, in which directory is located the generated file keystore

Tags: android, apk, keystore, signature, keytool

My question seems to be silly but I cannot get the generated file keystore after I executed the DOS command:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

In other words, where is the generated file "my-release-key.keystore"?

It is important to copy it in android/app before using gradle

Comment: It is in the current directory where you executed the command.

Comment: Yes, it is. But it was necessary to execute the keytool command in the JDK directory (not in another one). Otherwise, it does not work. So, after executing the keytool from its JDK directory, a keystore file is created